# Socket Programming: Bad address Error in read() when used in loop

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

I was trying to implement FTP Server as a part of an assignment and I wrote the following code to implement GET Command, which essentially reads file1 from server and stores it in file2.

```
int getCommandImpl(int clientSocket, char *file1, char *file2){
char *messageContent;
char buffer[256], userCommand[256], *tempString ;
int messageHead, endOfTransfer =0;
int messageLength;
sprintf(userCommand, "GET %s", file1);
messageLength = write(clientSocket,userCommand,strlen(userCommand));
if(messageLength <0){
    perror("Error sending data to server in RETR");
    return 0;
}
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file2, "w");
if(fp==NULL){
    printf("%s Can not be created\n", file2);
    return 0;
}
printf("Writing to file %s\n", file2);
while(!endOfTransfer){
    messageLength = read(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer)-1);
    if(messageLength == -1){
        perror("GET: Error in read() ");
        break;
    }
    //puts(buffer);
    printf("Buffer is %s with len %d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
    tempString = strdup(buffer);
    messageHead = atoi(strtok(tempString, " "));
    messageContent = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(messageHead == 0 && strlen(messageContent)==0){ //End of file transfer
        endOfTransfer = 1;
        break;
    }
    fwrite(messageContent, sizeof(char), sizeof(messageContent), fp);
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Buffer is %s with len %d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
fclose(fp);
return 1;
}
```

While running it, I am always getting the error "GET: Error in read() : Bad address". If I remove the statement

```
memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
```

I am getting a segmentation fault. I am assuming that the error has something to do with the string buffer being empty from the second iteration. 
Any help to solve this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: At the beginning of the `while(!endOfTransfer)` loop. you have: `messageLength = read(..., buffer, strlen(buffer)-1)`, but buffer is not initialized yet? You could end-up with `strlen(buffer)` to 0 so `strlen(buffer)-1` to be -1.

Comment: So what you meant probably is `sizeof(buffer) - 1`

Comment: Side issue: there is a memory leak in `tempString = strdup(buffer);` because you never `free(tempString);`

Comment: ... and in the two lines following, you are not checking the return value of `strtok()`, which might be `NULL`, but which you are processing.

Comment: I was sort of going by the logic that strlen() will give the size along with the terminating '\0' so strlen()-1. Turns out that logic was wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

@WeatherVane: Yup. The code is just too messy. Thanks for pointing them out :)

Comment: Assume nothing, be rigorous, `strlen(NULL)` will give a segmentation fault.

Comment: You don't need the `memset()` at all if you use the count returned by `read()` correctly.